# What is the purpose of `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` while creating a client using zmq?

Tags: python, sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm reading the source code of [AMP](https://amp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I'm confused about the purpose `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile` while the code creates a client using `zmq`.

Here is a sketch of how the code works:

Server:

```
import pexpect
import sys
import zmq
from socket import gethostname

python = sys.executable
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
port = socket.bind_to_random_port('tcp://*')
serverhostname = gethostname()
serversocket = '%s:%s' % (serverhostname, port)
workercommand = "%s -m %s %s" % (python, <python_module>, serversocket)

child = pexpect.spawn(workercommand)
child.expect('<amp-connect>')
```

By running the `<python-module>`, a client will be created

Client:

```
import zmq
import sys
import tempfile

print('<amp-connect>')
sys.stderr = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False, suffix='.stderr')
sys.stderr.write('initiated\n')
sys.stderr.flush()
context = zmq.Context()

sys.stderr.write('context started\n')
sys.stderr.flush()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)

sys.stderr.write('socket started\n')
sys.stderr.flush()
socket.connect('tcp://%s' % hostsocket)
```

My confusions:

1. What is the purpose of `sys.stderr = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False, suffix='.stderr')`? Why the client has to be created accompanied by those lines of `sys.stderr`?
2. Why `child.expect('<amp-connect>')` works in the code?

I wrote a similar code.

```
import pexpect
import sys
import test
python = sys.executable
workercommand = "%s -m %s" % (python, test)
child = pexpect.spawn(workercommand)
child.expect('<ahh>')
print(child.before)
```

in which `test.py` is just

```
print(100)
print('<ahh>')
```

However, I get the error: 
`pexpect.exceptions.EOF: End Of File (EOF). Empty string style platform.`

Why my code does not work?

Comment: looks they are separate things. `workercommand = "%s -m %s" % (python, test)' not run and quit;. so there's no chance to expect `<ahh>`